# Android Login App | Saving in database

Tags: java, android, save

I am making a login application for android devices and I've been wondering how to save the user's data (username, email, password, messages, ...). I also want to save other information.
What is the best way of doing this?
Could you please also explain how to do it or share a link where it's explained?
Thanks!

Martin W.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL Lite Database http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

if you want to store user data globally through out the application use Android User Session Management using Shared Preferences http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 0):

you can save the information in SQLite DB. You can see an example here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

(file DBHelper.java)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your use case.

For storing a lot of data I would recommend a database, for only simple datatypes you can use the SharedPreferences.

More information can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)